# Proxy server through list

Tags: proxy, socks

I have list of SOCKS5 proxy servers, which is frequently updated.
I want my traffic to go randomly or in order go through this list.

The server itself has to be SOCKS5 server. For example:

```
Data => 127.0.0.1:30000 => Proxy1
                        => Proxy2
                        => Proxy3
```

How can i do that ? I'm using [redsocks](https://github.com/darkk/redsocks) but it only supports one proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a setup similar to the [redsocks README](https://github.com/darkk/redsocks/blob/master/README) and the iptables RANDOM module to load balance/redirect each connection startup to each real proxy.